# Flash swf publishing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem here regarding flash+as3.

I'm makin an application that take data from XML file and show it on flash.

Now here's my problem.

When I preview the file, it went just fine. All the data been shown on the flash.
When I published it into .exe file, it also went just fine. All data been shown.

But...

When I published it into .swf file, there's a problem. All the graphical images been show, but data that i got from the XML file does not shown.

But when I took the published file and drag it into flash, it went just fine. All the data been shown.

I'm not quite sure what happen. Is there any setup that I have to do to solve this problem?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible problems:

1. your path to the xml data is relative and your published swf can't find it.
2. More likely your xml data is on a web server and you are looking at the swf through a local webpage using file:///myfile.html. This fails because of security. Adobe have decided that local swfs can only look at local content, and network swfs can only look at network content. This rule is disregarded in the flash ide because if you have the flash ide you are a developer and you should know what you are doing.

Check out your swf on a web server and report back.